# How can I delete a row in ag-grid while using InfiniteRowModel?

Tags: ag-grid

I'm trying to remove rows from my ag-grid dynamically. My grid currently uses `rowModelType: "infinite"`.  I've been using the [updateRowData](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/) function for adding and updating, but when I try to remove a row using this function:

```
deleteRow(record) {
        this.agGrid.api.updateRowData({ remove: [record] });
}
```

I get the following warning in my console:

> ag-grid: updateRowData for InfiniteRowModel does not support remove or update, only add

I've used it for both add and update and it's been working. How can I delete rows while using an infinite row model?

Comment: Please qualify what you mean by "best" in objective terms. Otherwise this risks getting closed as 'primarily opinion-based'.

Comment: @TylerH Whichever way uses best practices.

Comment: That's not objective, and best practices questions are also off-topic on Stack Overflow for the same reason: opinions.

Comment: I’ve updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working with `InfiniteRowModel` or `ServerSideRowModel`, [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) doesn't support deleting or updating the records.

It suggests us to `gridApi.purgeServerSideCache()`.

I researched a bit myself regarding accessing the row data in these row model, but it doesn't provide access to it. So better to purge.